# Errors during Login system

Tags: php, forms, authentication

Right, I have been having problems with certain bits of code. 
Here is a link to the site http://travels.sdolby.net/login.php whenever I try to register, it comes up with errors, would someone be able to tell me what is wrong with my code?

Here is a link to the code I have written where you can download it an have a look. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

PS, the username and password in the SQL are deliberately blanked out.

Edit: I have fixed the first problem thank you to everyone who helped.
However, I have another error that I can't fix it. I think it's something wrong with the log.php file.

It won't let me post the code so here is a link to a txt you can see the log.php and reg.php as they may both be at fault
http://travels.sdolby.net/problem.txt

Comment: please post your code. the error its giving is just an echo typed by you.

Comment: I will post the code but there is a lot of it.

Comment: yeah post it in pastebin.com if theres a lot of it makes easier to read thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

**1.** use **filter_vars** to validate data **eregi** is not the best choice.

**2.** the **mysql_*** functions are **DEPRECATED** use MySQLi or PDO.

**3.** Your SQL-Querys are susceptible for SQL injections!

**4.** configure **correctly**: You have a bad Hostname in your SQL-Connection (see **sql.php** on **Line 4**).

Comment: Ok, I will have a look when I get ome from school later today. Thank you for this help. :)

Comment: the eregi is because it works properly and tried the filter vars ting. The hostname had a misplaced space.